# Forum Registration where submit also sends info Campaign Monitor

Tags: members, forum, registration

I have a client who would like to have members register for the discussion forums and when the user submits the form if they selected the checkbox to recieve a newsletter the form would both register the member (save info to EE) and submit their name, email and phone number (not sure if CC takes phone numbers) to campaign monitor.

First question - is it possible to have one form that submits to two different action urls?
If so what would be the best way to set this up in the forum templates? I'm using a [modified scaffold theme](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/scaffold).

Second - assuming this can be done the next step involves getting the email, name and phone inputs to be used for both forms. The issue I see here is that the inputs have different names for the EE end and for Campaign Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've submitted form data over to SalesForce using PHP in an extension called on Freeform's post submit hook. The same would apply here. I suspect you want the [member_member_register hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_register/index.html#member-member-register).

Just write your extension to fire on that hook, and you can work with the API however you need to. You'll load data from the member database, and post it over to Campaign Monitor.

That said, there are [a bunch of add-ons that claim to post new members to Campaign Monitor](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=campaign%20monitor&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2). Have you examined those?

Comment: thanks - hadn't even thought aobut addons and there does appear to be a few that will do what I need. Thanks.